# Questions regarding domains

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For 
$f_1, f_2: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n \cup \{\infty\}$

What is $\text{dom}(f_1+f_2)$

Will this result be extended to the multiplication/division and subtraction of the two different domains?

My initial/intuitive guess what that $\text{dom}(f_1+f_2) = \text{dom}(f_1) \cup \text{dom}(f_2)$

But it is my understanding that the answer is $\text{dom}(f_1) \cap \text{dom}(f_2)$. Can someone provide an intuitive explanation of why this is so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a very simple example: $f_1 = \sqrt{x}$ and $f_2 = \sqrt{x-3}$, defined in $\mathbb{R^2}$. We know the domain of $f_1$ to be $\mathbb{R^+}\cup\{0\}$ and the domain of $f_2$ to be $\mathbb{R^+}\setminus(0,3)$. According to your intuitive guess, then, the domain of $f_1+f_2$ would be the less restrictive $\mathbb{R^+}\cup\{0\}$, but can you calculate $\sqrt{x-3}$ for, say, $x=2\in\mathbb{R^+}\cup\{0\}$? Of course not. This shows your intuition to be off base.

As for the correct general interpretation, a hint would be to consider what
$$
\mathrm{dom}(f_1)\cap\mathrm{dom}(f_2)\cap\cdots\cap\mathrm{dom}(f_{n-1})\cap\mathrm{dom}(f_n)
$$
actually *means*. When are all the functions defined? Consider this and I think you can piece out the rest.

Comment: thank you, via example It proves to be much easier to understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well to be in $\text{dom}\, f+g$, a number must be in both $\text{dom}\,f$ and $\text{dom}\,g$, since by definition $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$. In other words, you can't plug a number into $f+g$ if you can't plug it into $f$ or plug it into $g$.